# How to add a private user page populated from sql?

Tags: mysql, user-registration, user-access

I have taken over management of a Boy Scout website for around 75 kids. The site is a vanilla WordPress site and has no access control (other than admin).

I would like a scout/parent to be able to login and 
view private information specific to the scout. The scout should only be able to view their own information.

Ideally there would be a user registration (with validation) and, for validated users, a page that has some fields populated from an SQL database (or CSV, or whatever).

While I am comfortable with PHP etc, I am hoping to pass the management of the site off at some point, and so would rather stick with vanilla solutions, if
possible.

I have looked at various possibilities (for example, SentryLogin, Ragic, etc),
but any solution I can think of (using these possibilities) quickly becomes burdensome.

Any suggestions or directions would be much appreciated.